# Both methods have same erasures

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I have read similar questions, and know generic erasures will cause this error IN SAME CLASS. But I cannot understand why following code dont work.

I designed some examples. And found many many things confusing.

```
public static class Father<S> {

    public void foo(Set<String> s) {...}

    public void bar(S s) {...}

    public void baz(String s) {...}
}


public static class Son<E> extends Father {

    public void foo(Set<String> s) {...} **// error**

    public void bar(E e) {...} **// error**
 // public void bar(Object e) {...} // This works

    public void baz(String s) {...}
}


public static class Daughter<E> extends Father<T> {

    public void foo(Set<String> s) {...} **// error**

    public void bar(Object e) {...}

    public void baz(String s) {...} **// error**
}
```

As you can see, I got several erros. Here is my questions:

1. Let's focus on `Father` and `Son`. Why does `baz` work, while `foo` does not?
2. Let's see `bar` in `Son`. Why `Object e` works, while `E e` fails? I think `E` will be erased to `Object`?
3. Let's see `Daughter`, why `baz` fails, comparing to `Son`?

Please anyone tell me why this occurs? Many thanks!
(I know I should not use raw classes. But why this causes error? )

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `Son<E>` extends a raw `Father` class.

Therefore `foo` and `bar` of the `Son` class don't override

```
public void foo(Set<String> s) {}

public void bar(S s) {}
```

of the `Father` class, which (after erasure) become

```
public void foo(Set s) {}

public void bar(Object s) {}
```

and have the same erasure of the methods of the same name in the `Son` class.

Changing the declaration of `Son` to

```
public static class Son<E> extends Father<E>
```

will resolve the errors.

The `baz` method has no issues since it has no generic arguments, so `baz` of the sub-class overrides `baz` of the base-class.

In your `Daughter` class, it's not clear where `T` is coming from. If you change `T` to `E`, all the errors go away.

Oh, and `void bar(Object e)` works in the original example since it overrides `void bar(S s)` of `Father` (due to the fact the `Son` extends a raw `Father`).

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
public class Son<E> extends Father {
```

You are using a raw `Father` in the definition of the class extending.
**It is a bad practice**.
You should rather write :

```
public class Son<E> extends Father<E> {
```

Using raw types has also consequences in terms of inheritancy.
From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) :

> The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the
>   erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of the
>   parameterizations of the generic type.

and :

> The supertype of a class may be a raw type. Member accesses for the
>   class are treated as normal, and member accesses for the supertype are
>   treated as for raw types.

As a consequence, `Son` doesn't consider generics in the parent class.
For `Son` , this inherited method  :

```
public void foo(Set<String> s) {
}
```

is indeed bound as :

```
public void foo(Set s) {
}
```

So, the child and the parent methods have the same erasure but the child method doesn't override the parent method as you don't use exactly the same type :

```
public void foo(Set<String> s) {...} **// error**
```

If you override in this way to be conform to the raw version of the `Father` :

```
public void foo(Set s) {...}
```

it will compile.

For `bar()` method with generics, it is exactly the same thing.

This :

```
public void bar(E e)
```

will be bound as :

```
public void bar(Object e)
```

And you get the same problem...

I will not explain all the points as I don't think that it is helpful.
What you get is the result of bad practices.

The morale is you have not to use raw types for class designed to work with generics as it may create serious side effects on their initial intention and usage of the class.

This

```
public static class Son<E> extends Father {
```

should be :

```
public static class Son<E> extends Father<E>  {
```

And this :

```
public static class Daughter<E> extends Father<T> {
```

should be :

```
public static class Daughter<E> extends Father<E> {
```

Comment: T.T I know I should not use raw class. But I really want to know why it causes error.